# How to apply a running function inR

Tags: r

I need to develop a function in R which can be used to compute time varying variable API which is defines as: api(t)=k*api(t-1)+ppt(t).

```
ppt=round(c(0.0,0.0,0.0,runif(25, 0.0, 15.5),0.0,0.0),digit=1)
api=c(5.75,rep(NA,29))
k=0.85
f <- function(k,api,ppt,...){
for (i in 2:30){
api[i]=k*api[i-1]+ppt[i]
return(api)}}
f(k=k,api=api,ppt=ppt)
```

when I apply the above function I am only getting the first value. 
I appreciate you help.

Comment: have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: Can you formulate what it is exactly that you're struggling with?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the question to include some data.

Comment: o_O ... no range for t, p=NA on first iteration as there's no p(t-1), let's do infinite recursion ... Please be specific on your question, SO is not a free code service, show some efforts solving it by yourself and to express cleanly your goal.

Comment: @mtoto please find the edits have made to my initial question

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple recursion:

```
calculateP <- function(startP, t, k, j) {
  if (t == 0) {
     return (stp)
  } 
  return (k[t]*calcP(stp, t-1, k,j) + j[t])
}
```

Seems to work pretty well.